# Assigning the value of a fetch request to a Javascript Object Property returns undefined

Tags: javascript, oop, object, fetch-api

Fetching data via the Fetch API,  I need to assign the response to a variable,  which will be used in many instances,  like a global value.

The most adequate way to do so is to create an object and assign the fetch response to one of it's properties.

```
  var number = 0;

  fetch(url, numberValue);  // fetch data from API,  returns a string like "5489721"

  function numberValue(response)  {// invoked by fetch, it's parameter is the fetch response.
    this.number = response:
    // console,log('number='+this.number): // 43090
   }

   console.log("number value outside function value="+ new numberValue().number):  // prints undefined.
```

However I found that inside the function that creates the object,  the assigned value works well,  but if I invoke the object outside it's constructor function  I get a value of "undefined".

However if I assign a fixed value,  I get the correct value which makes me think that the problem is with the json response,  however it works perfectly inside it's constructor.

The fetch function is this:

```
function fetchGet(url, functionName) {
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET'
 }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
 }).then(function(json) {
    functionName(json);  // here I invoke other function to process response.
 }).catch(function(err) {
}
```

It's invoked on page load,  like this:

```
 var url =""; // API endpoint, gives a plain "525554"
 fetchGet(url, value);

 function value (response) {
   console.log('response='+response);  //52554
 }
```

However what I need,  beyond capturing the plain value,  is to expose this value in the namespace which will be used bay other functions.

Comment: Can you log the JSON response to see if your getting a number back?

Comment: In your example, you do not assign any value to the "response" variable, which is then assigned to this.number, so the value is undefined. Please provide your full code if this is not the issue

Comment: The response is a json string,  exactly like this "32250",  it's the output of an API.

Comment: Please include the fetch api code so, it's easier to obtain the context/perspective from which you are utilizing this callback.

Comment: your (first) console.log is not logging the correct value, because `fetch` is asynchronous, and you're trying to log the value before it's been fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Contents of: data/example-fetch-1.json

```
{
  "foo": "Hello",
  "bar": "World"
}
```

Contents of: data/example-fetch-1.json

```
{
  "foo": "Be",
  "bar": "Yah"
}
```

Class definition, usage:

```
'use strict';
class jsonData {
    constructor(url) {
        let thisObject = this;
        thisObject.dataJson = null;
        thisObject.dataUrl = url;
        thisObject.fetchData = function (url) {
            if (!!url) {
                thisObject.dataUrl = url;
            }
            fetch(thisObject.dataUrl, {
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(function (fetchResponse) {
                return fetchResponse.json();
            }).then(function (fetchResponseJson) {
                thisObject.postProcess(fetchResponseJson);
            }).catch(function (doh) {
                throw new Error(doh);
            });
        }
        thisObject.message = function () {
            let bar = 'DOH';
            let foo = 'doh';
            let jsonDataExists = !!thisObject.dataJson;
            if (jsonDataExists) {
                let incomingData = thisObject.dataJson;
                bar = incomingData.bar || bar;
                foo = incomingData.foo || foo;
            }
            return foo+' '+bar+'!';
        }
        thisObject.postProcess = function (responseJson) {
            thisObject.dataJson = responseJson;
            console.log('jsonData.message() = ', thisObject.message());
        }
    }
}
var jsonDataGetter = new jsonData('data/example-fetch-1.json');
jsonDataGetter.fetchData();
jsonDataGetter.fetchData('data/example-fetch-2.json');
```

Comment: Using this code,  gives me always the '43090' value,  instead of the response value.

Comment: So, you are looking to just have a callback function return whatever value response is?

Comment: Yes,  I need to expose the value of response as a variable which can be accessed by other functions. I fetch a json encoded strign from an API, gives me responses like "41087",  need to expose this value, which changes everytime it is fetched. The function value() is invoked by the fetch method and receives as parameter the fetch response.